# Need a noob guide on using the UIPickerView and UIActionSheet together(only show pickerview when a textfield is tap)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uipickerview, uiactionsheet

I have been searching for days on on how I can use a pickerview on my textfield... I am very new to Ios programming and I have been searching the web for snippets of code that I can use on my program..

Basically this is just what I want: 
I have a one of my textfield that ask for which Equipment type.. there is only 4 items to select on.
I want the program to show the picker view when they tap the equiptextfield and fill it with the item that they selected from the picker view.. then the picker view should be dismissed or go to the next field.

I found out online that the best way to do this is to use UIActionSheet to show/hide the pickerview only when that textfield was selected.

I need to know what I have to add on these items:
-my nib file(currently it has 1 view with a scrollview under it and all the fields is on it)
View
 -scroll View
  -my textfields under it...

-my header file... im really a noob so I really need to ask for the code

-my implementation file.. same as the header, I need the code please

Please dont think I didnt do my search because I did and there is just so much stuff online that its hard to figure out which to use, and those that I tried gave me errors.

thank you so much for any help anyone can provide.

Comment: Sorry, don't expect people here to code for you for free. Look at examples, look at apple documentation for the appropriate classes. Try to do it yourself. Then when you have specific errors, you should come back and ask about them. Sorry that there is so much to learn. Over the last 15 years, I've accumulated a dozen books on Objective-C, Cocoa, and iOS plus lots of trial and error and lots of web based tutorials.

Comment: i understand and i guess looking at it in a different prospective i might think the same.. I have search online and found this to be the closest of what I was wanting to do but there is things I didnt understand from his codes [link](http://www.wetware.co.nz/2009/02/how-to-popup-a-uipickerview-from-the-bottom-of-a-uiscrollview-in-response-to-uitextfield-selection/)

Comment: It looks like exactly what you're asking for. If you don't understand what he's written, you can ask specifically about what you don't understand. Or tell us what errors you're getting implementing his solution.

Comment: first of all I wasnt sure where to put the first block of code.. do I put that on my .h or .m? second I didnt know if I had to put a pickerview on my xib file.

Comment: Then you probably need to learn more about programming Objective-C. .m file is your implementation file. That is where you implement your classes.

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides a good example of UIKit's controls. [UICatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Introduction/Intro.html)

> This sample is a catalog exhibiting many views and controls in the
>   UIKit framework, along with their various properties and styles.
>
> If you need code to create specific UI controls or views, refer to
>   this sample and it should give you a good head start in building your
>   user interface. In most cases you can simply copy and paste the code
>   snippets you need.

Try. Do not be afraid to fail. Errors are experience too.

Btw, why are you using UITextField for such tasks? I suppose, the better way to **select** the one option from four is to use UISegmentedControl with 4 segments.